# How to get system time using setText in Android?

Tags: textview, android

I am new to Android development. Kindly help me out with this code.

I want to access the system time in my counter, i.e. in `setText`. As for now I have used some random date and time but I want that to be changed to current date and time.

Here is the code:

```
package countdowntimer.android;


import java.util.Date;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.System;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MActivity extends Activity {

        TextView day,hour,min,sec;
        int iDay,iHour,iMin,iSec;
        MyCount counter;
        Date endDate = null;
        Date startDate = null;
        NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss");


        day=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.day);
        hour=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hour);
        min=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.min);
        sec=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sec);
        myFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
        final EditText end=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.end);
        final EditText start=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.start);

            start.setText("2011-09-08-00:00:00");


            Button btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {

        try {
            endDate = outputFormat.parse(end.getText().toString());
            startDate=outputFormat.parse(start.getText().toString());


        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage()
                     ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }


        long diffInMis= endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        if(diffInMis<0){
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please, Enter valid Time..."
             ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
        long diff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMis);
        iDay=(int) (diff/(60*60*24));
        long lday= (diff%(60*60*24));
        iHour=(int)(lday/3600);
        long lhour= (lday%(60*60));
        iMin=(int)(lhour/60);
        long lmin= (lhour%(60));
        iSec=(int)(lmin);
        day.setText(String.valueOf(iDay).toString()+" Day ");
        hour.setText(String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iHour)).toString());
        min.setText(":"+String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iMin)).toString());
        sec.setText(":"+String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iSec)).toString());
        counter = new MyCount(iSec*1000,1000);
        counter.start();}
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }   };     });
        Button btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        counter.cancel();
        }         }); }
        public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        counter = new MyCount(60000,1000);
        counter.start();
        iMin-=1;
        if(iMin>-1)
        min.setText(":"+String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iMin)).toString());
        else{
        iMin=59;
        min.setText(":"+String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iMin)).toString());
        iHour-=1;
        if(iHour>-1)
        hour.setText(String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iHour)).toString());
        else{
        iHour=11;
        hour.setText(String.valueOf(myFormat.format(iHour)).toString());
        iDay-=1;
        if(iDay>-1)
        day.setText(" "+String.valueOf(iDay).toString());
        else{
        day.setText("Time is over");
        hour.setText("");
        min.setText("");
        sec.setText("");
        counter.cancel();
        }}}}
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        sec.setText(":"+String.valueOf(myFormat.format(millisUntilFinished/1000)));
        }}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the system time with

```
Calendar.getInstance();
int hh = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);//or
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String aux[] = sdf.format(cal.getTime()).split("/");//process the array from here
```

Note that you must

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Comment: thanx for help but i want to modify my start.setText("2011-09-08-00:00:00");
in such a way that it shows the current time and date...plz help me out  with this..

Comment: yes..actually its a timer it gets system's time and date by itself  and matches with the date i:e. end date, and starts the timer=end date-start date.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");start.setText(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+"-"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTES)+":"+Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECONDS));

Comment: @ Tepes Lucian.....Thanx a lot..sir...it worked...m really grateful to you....thanx a tob..:-)

Comment: If @tepes provided the correct answer, you can (and should) accept it by clicking the green tick to the left.